# Blender solidify problems

Tags: mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier

[image]
Sticking out of the donut. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the icing thingy sticking out.[image]

Comment: At some point you probably accidentally dragged one or more vertices by a lot. Maybe you've hidden some verties, then moved the rest, but when you solidify, the hidden vertices are also used and produce visible vertices that are out of place.

Comment: The little blue and white icon on the right hand side above the modifier that looks like a computer monitor can be used to toggle the modifier visibility on or off. I suggest you turn it off temporarily so you can get a better look at your real mesh topology to see what's going on. Looks like a vert just got dragged like Markus said. Either bring it back into place manually, or delete all its components, select the "ring" around the resulting gap in the mesh, then select `Face > Grid Fill` from the menu at the top of the viewport.

Comment: Additionally, however, I'll give the same advice I always give regarding the donut tutorial - Every time you make a mistake, or things don't turn out right, close the program (no saving) and start over from the _very beginning_. It might seem like a pain, but the repetition will make you much faster and more comfortable with blender's systems. By the end, you'll be able to do the entire donut scene in less than 10 mins with no guidance.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of starting over cause it looks like I can't fix the problem with the icing.